# Is it possible to send Magento Event Observer result to Custom API?

Tags: magento, observer-pattern

I wonder, is it possible to send Magento Event Observer result to custom API?

I'm trying to create an API to get new order via XML-RPC. Are there any examples around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used any Magento Web Services, via XML-RPC. However, I have used normal SOAP Core API & SOAP V2 Web Services of Magento, and if you are using either of these two processes, then there is a solution for you.

For Magento Core API, the required method name is "[`sales_order.list`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/sales_order#sales_order.list)", and for the SOAP V2, the required method name is "`salesOrderList`". The return type will be array of orders. The main useful thing in this Web Service method, is that there is an option to use filters. Now this filter will help you a lot in getting the new orders from a specified date & time, so you can pretty much use it to your own requirement.

For the V2 Web Services method "`salesOrderList`", you can use the filter as:-

```
<salesOrderList>
    <sessionId>51ba5b3ff707f874fd76369d65bb1b7f</sessionId>
    <complex_filter>
        <key>created_at</key>
        <value>
            <key>gt</key>
            <value>2011-07-14 13:38:56</value>
        </value>
    </complex_filter>
</salesOrderList>
```

What the above sample code will do is that it will fetch / retrieve those orders in array format, which have been created after 01:38:56 PM of 14th July, 2011.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to get only new orders made by customers instead of filtering the salesorder.list?Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is what I said in the above post. Let me tell you in more details... Try to store the date passed in calling this method for the filter "`created_at`" in a variable or file or database. Now after the result is retrieved, fetch the last greatest date available from all the present orders, and store this date instead of the previous value. Now again, when you will call the Web Service method, you will be using the last stored "`created_at`" value. So you see, that you aren't fetching any duplicate values at all.

Comment: Do i have to use filters in sales_order.List?Thanks

Comment: By the way,is it possible to refresh the list every time a client made an order.Thanks..

Comment: Yes, you can call this API using a cron with the updated "`created_at`" date & time, so that the new Orders can come in. And the example which I showed above is for the method "`salesOrderList`" (of SOAP V2 of Magento). But if you are using the method "`sales_order.list`" (of Magento Core API), then you will need to use the same sort of filter (with "`created_at`", "`gt`" & last updated date), but with different syntax.